# v-card-media with base64 image

Tags: coldfusion, vuejs2, captcha, vuetify.js, taffy

I am creating a captcha image in ColdFusion and returning it as a REST feed with Taffy. It is then shown in Vuetify

**ColdFusion / Taffy code**

```
<cfscript>
  component extends="taffy.core.resource" taffy_uri="/captcha" {

  function get() hint="Sends one out" {

  var captcha   = CreateUUID().right(4) & DayOfWeekAsString(DayOfWeek(now())).left(1).lcase() & "!";

  // This is ColdFusion
  var tempFile = "ram:///#captcha#.txt";

  var myImage = ImageCreateCaptcha(100, 300, captcha, "low");

  ImageWriteBase64(myImage, tempFile, "png", true, true);

  var myfile = FileRead(tempFile);
  FileDelete(tempFile);


  return rep({'status' : 'success', 'time' : GetHttpTimeString(now()),
    'captcha_hash' : hash(captcha), 'captcha_image' : myFile
    });
}
...
</cfscript>
```

It returns something like this:

```
{"status":"success","captcha_image":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG /d67W8EALALKJQAABBYAAAILABAYAEAILAAdr...
```

**Vue**

I can display the image via

```
<img :src="captcha_image" height="100px;">
```

**Vuetify**

If I don't use a height, the image does not come out at all

If I use a height like this, it comes out with the wrong aspect ratio.

```
<v-card-media :src="captcha_image" height="100px"></v-card-media>
```

Is there a work around? Or is `<v-card-media` the wrong tool for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `v-card-media` use the image as a background image of a `div` with fixed height.

If you want to keep the aspect ratio. You can use `<img />` tag with a `width="100%"` instead.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ..." width="100%">
```

demo: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/bMrBWx?&editors=101

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card>
          <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ..." width="100%">
          <v-card-title primary-title>
              ...
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-actions>
              ...
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: after giving `width="100%"` attribute that image based on base64 successfully rendered